# How to play video on Next button clicked in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have array list of videos so users can watch video in android app. I would like to add Next and Previous button for playing next or previous video after current video is ended. I googled it but to no avail. I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We can't help you answer questions about code you don't have. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MediaPlayer class then maybe try adding logic to the callback for `setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)` that takes the user to the next video by getting what's next from the list and starting playback.

See [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) for more information. Without knowing what you're trying it's almost impossible to help you solve your problem. Please share the code from your solution related to your question.